# Best way to schedule job to run every other day?

Tags: bash, cron

I want to run a cronjob to run every night and run a backup script but I want to keep two days of backups before I replace the oldest one.
The only way I can think of doing this is doing a day of the week cronjob and running two cronjobs each replacing the one that itself did two days before.
Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*/2` for day of the month, like so:

```
01 23 */2 * * command_name
```

This runs at 23:01 on the 1st, 3rd, ..., 31st of every month.

**To run two cron jobs on alternate days**:

```
01 23 1-31/2 * * command_name1
01 23 2-30/2 * * command_name2
```

**SEE ALSO:**

> The time and date fields are:
>
> ```
>    field          allowed values
>    -----          --------------
>    minute         0-59
>    hour           0-23
>    day of month   1-31
>    month          1-12 (or names, see below)
>    day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
> ```
>
> A field may contain an asterisk (`*`), which always stands for
> "first-last".
> ...
> Step values
> are also permitted after an asterisk, so if specifying a job to be
> run every two hours, you can use "`*/2`".

Comment: Thanks how would I do the second command for the second other days of the month.
Your example would run on the 1st 3th 5th and so on.
What about the 2nd 4th 6th?

Comment: @StefanMarkov Updated the answer.

Comment: That's actually not "every other day". Because if you do `01 23 1-31/2 * * command_name1`  then `command_name1` will run on Jan, 31 and also on Feb 1, ie on two days in a row ... Defining a real "every other day" is extremly cumbersome, because you would need to define for each month separately on which day do run (ie run on Jan 1,3,5, ... 31, Feb 2,4,6,8, .. 28Mar 2, 4, 6, ... 30, Apr 1,3,5 ... 29, and so on and so forth). And for leap years, even that logic wouldn't be correct, because it will produce a 2 day gap between Feb 28 and Mar 2 ...